# log - derivative transformation.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

That problem actually came out from Advanced Macroeconomics exercise, where one needs to transform an elasticity of substitution between capital and effective labor in the gross production function.
Formulating problem mathematically, there is a function $F = F(x,y)$. Then one constructs a derivative/function:
$$\frac{\partial(x/y)}{\partial(F_x/F_y)}\cdot\frac{F_x/F_y}{x/y} = \frac{\partial \log(x/y)}{\partial \log(F_x/F_y)},$$

and "transform" this derivative into:
$$\frac{\partial \log(x/F)}{\partial \log(F_x)}.
$$

Here we assume that the function has all the needed partial derivatives and they are continuous in a point of interest.
So the question is how one may prove this transformation, and, probably, which fact one may use to prove this transition? I would appreciate any idea on how to proceed.

**corrections:**

Function $F$ should be *homothetic*.